# Select distinct user_id from a table for each request type

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a table with 4 columns:

`ID`, `USER_ID`, `SOURCE`, `CREATED_DATE`

In that table is the following data:

```
ID  USER_ID SOURCE          CREATED_DATE
1   25      PURCHASE        2012-01-01 12:30:00
2   26      PLEDGE          2012-01-01 12:40:00
3   25      PLEDGE          2012-01-01 12:50:00
4   25      PURCHASE        2012-01-14 12:00:00
```

Now as you can see, I have 4 rows of data, and two unique users. User (25) made 3 transactions (two purchases and one pledge), user (26) made one transaction – (one pledge)

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I need to select ALL transactions from this table, but I want to select a UNIQUE user for each REQUEST TYPE (source), and that row needs to be the EARLIEST TRANSACTION.

My expected result data would be:

```
ID  USER_ID SOURCE          CREATED_DATE
1   25      PURCHASE        2012-01-01 12:30:00
2   26      PLEDGE          2012-01-01 12:40:00
3   25      PLEDGE          2012-01-01 12:00:00
```

User (25) made TWO PURCHASES (one on 2012-01-01 and one on 2012-01-14) – the first is the one that gets returned.

This is the SQL I have come up with so far:

```
    SELECT 
        Supporter.user_id,
        MIN(Supporter.created) as created,
        Supporter.*,
        Supporter.source
    FROM
        supporters AS Supporter

    GROUP BY Supporter.source
    ORDER BY Supporter.created ASC
```

Now, this gets me really close, except it only selects ONE of the user id’s (the one with two items – a pledge and a purchase). If I could figure out how to select the data on both users, that would be what I need to do! Can anyone see what I am possibly doing wrong here, or missing?

Comment: What is `Supporter.source` and how does it relate to your example data?

Comment: Sorry - REQUEST_TYPE is source. I spent 15 minutes writing this out and I still made a mistake! doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by source and by user id

Something like this

```
SELECT 
    Supporter.user_id,
    MIN(Supporter.created) as created,
    Supporter.*,
    Supporter.source
FROM
    supporters AS Supporter

GROUP BY Supporter.user_id, Supporter.source
ORDER BY Supporter.created ASC
```

Comment: Seems to work. I can't believe it was that simple! You are a gentleman and a scholar!